# Magento2: Errors installing Sample Data: Class "\Magento\SampleData\Model" not found / no commands defined in "sampledata" namespace

Tags: magento2, installation, sample-data

I am trying to install `Magento2` version `1.0.0-beta`.

I followed instructions about installing sample data from: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/sample-data.html

I enabled sample data before installing Magento and at the end of installation, I got the following error:

> Error during sample data installation: 
>   Source class "\Magento\SampleData\Model" for "Magento\SampleData\Model\Logger" generation does not exist

I then tried installing sample data after installing Magento.
I am getting the following error while installing sample data after installing Magento:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   There are no commands defined in the "sampledata" namespace.

Comment: use the master branch instead of develop branch

Comment: Just found the same issue in Magento Version 2.3.4 Edition Enterprise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to delete old magento2 files and directory & redo the whole thing.

- Deleted the whole magento2 directory
- Cloned magento2 again
- Enabled sample data before installing Magento2
- Installed Magento2
- Finally, done!

Magento2 installed successfully with sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Did you download version 1.0.0-beta from the releases page (or master branch), or off of the current develop branch?

My understanding is that the develop branch is not stable/sample data won't work, but it should be fine if you're using the official beta1 release. You can find that here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/releases

Comment: `git branch` shows `* 1.0.0-beta`. I am using the `1.0.0-beta` from the releases page.